# Skip non-existing source files when compiling installer in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

In the `[Files]` section, I have to achieve that by trying to compiling a file that does not exist, the compiler does not fail and follow its course.

For example in this code:

```
[Files]
Source: "D:\{#pais}\{#modulo}\IMG\image.png"; \
    DestDir: "{userdocs}\Qlik\Sense\Content\Default\{#senseAppDir}\IMG\"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion
```

If the file `image.png` doesn't exists, I want the compiler to skip it and continue.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

1. Use [`skipifsourcedoesntexist` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=skipifsourcedoesntexist):

   ```
   Source: "D:\{#pais}\{#modulo}\IMG\image.png"; \
       DestDir: "{userdocs}\Qlik\Sense\Content\Default\{#senseAppDir}\IMG\"; \
       Flags: ignoreversion skipifsourcedoesntexist
   ```
2. Use [preprocessor directive `#ifexist`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=ifdef):

   ```
   [Files]
   #ifexist "D:\" + pais + "\" + modulo + "\IMG\image.png"
   Source: "D:\{#pais}\{#modulo}\IMG\image.png"; \
       DestDir: "{userdocs}\Qlik\Sense\Content\Default\{#senseAppDir}\IMG\"; \
       Flags: ignoreversion 
   #endif
   ```