# Conditionally include folders in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to create an installer with Inno Setup that will statically include a folder if it exists. This folder will be installed on the user system if a specific directory already exists on the user's system.

For example, there are configurations specific to 2017, 2018, 2019. If *I have* a `CC2017` folder, then include it in the installer. The installer will put the folder on the user's system in their 2017 folder if it exists.

I use variables to define some of the path and have formatted them without brackets based on [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112047/skip-non-existing-source-files-when-compiling-installer-in-inno-setup).

```
#ifexist projpath + "\" + reponame + "\Plug-Ins\Windows\CC2017\"  
Source: "{#projpath}\{#reponame}\Plug-Ins\Windows\CC2017\{#pluginname}\*"; \
  DestDir: "{sd}\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe InDesign CC 2017\Plug-Ins\{#pluginname}"; \
  Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs replacesameversion; \
  Check: MyDirCheck(ExpandConstant('{sd}\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe InDesign CC 2017'))  
#endif
```

I know it isn't checking correctly because the file size is much smaller when I add the `ifexist` directives. The [Inno Setup docs](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=ifdef) mention "files" but not folders so I'm suspicious that it might not support checking folders.

What is wrong with the syntax?

*I'm using Inno Setup 6.0.2 on Mac 10.13.6*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Use [`skipifsourcedoesntexist` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=skipifsourcedoesntexist):

   ```
   [Files]
   Source: "folder\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: skipifsourcedoesntexist
   ```
2. Use [`#if` preprocessor directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=if) along with [`DirExists` preprocessor function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=direxists):

   ```
   [Files]
   #if DirExists("folder")
   Source: "folder\*"; DestDir: "{app}"
   #endif
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Even after all my searching, those options didn't come up in the docs. Thanks for pointing them out!